# Slick with MySql and Emojis

Tags: mysql, scala, slick

I am trying to persist emojis to a column in a MySQL table using Slick.

I have a `my.cnf` config file that has the following character-set related settings:

```
[mysqld]
character-set-client-handshake = FALSE
character-set-server = utf8mb4
collation-server = utf8mb4_unicode_ci
init-connect='SET NAMES utf8mb4'
```

And my jdbc string looks like so:

```
url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/mydb?useLegacyDatetimeCode=false&serverTimezone=UTC&useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=UTF-8"
```

Now at first I wasn't sure about the usage of just "UTF-8" for the `characterEncoding` parameter, but from what I read when you combine it with the `useUnicode=true` parameter then it should work.

When Slick executes the following sql:

```
insert into `content` (`id`,`title`)  values ('f1291f0d-eeee-4379-84ef-5d62e2870407','This is an emoji')
```

I get the following error:

```
java.sql.SQLException: Incorrect string value: '\xF0\x9F\x8D\x82 |...' for column 'title' at row 1
```

I am using MySQL `v5.7.26`

Can anyone see what might be missing?

Comment: I don't know much about MySQL. But you're specifying `character-set-server = utf8mb4` in `my.cnf` and `characterEncoding=UTF-8` in the connection string. According to the manual (https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/charset-unicode.html), utf8 is an alias for utf8mb3, and UTF-8 isn't mentioned at all. Have you tried setting `characterEncoding` to `utf8mb4` or removing it entirely?

Comment: @MatthiasBerndt the details are a bit vague but my understanding was that by adding `useUnicode=true` it was supposed to tell it to use `utf8mb4`. I would *think* that the `character-set-client-handshake=false` setting should make whatever I pass in on the jdbc string moot anyway!

Comment: `useUnicode` doesn't seem to exist at all. It's not mentioned in the manual:
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/8.0/en/connector-j-reference-configuration-properties.html

Comment: Oh, remember I’m using MySQL 5, and also the connector v5.1.26. The option is mentioned here for the 5.1.x connector: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/5.1/en/connector-j-connp-props-miscellaneous.html I’ll try a new recent version of the 5.1 connector (unless I can use the v8 connector??)

Comment: Oh it does! https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/8.0/en/connector-j-versions.html